# How to create dynamic TextBoxes in MVC3 and store it in SQL database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie, i read MVC Movie App tutorial and created an AddressBook based on that, i am using ADO.NET Entity DataModel for stroing values in Database table, as i do not know anyother way, i am storing following values in my table-
Id (primary key auto)
name
gender
phoneno(Heres the problem i want to add multiple phone numbers, i want to add text boxes on clicking "add" link )

not only i want to add text boxes on view but also store it in database table , how do i do that? 
REMEMBER i am a newbie keep it simple

Answer (score 1):

If you need more than one phone number for same Contact. It is a **ONE to MANY** relation ship. that means you need a seperate table to store your Phone numbers

I would create a new table called `PhoneNumber` like this structure

```
PHONE_NUMBER_ID (INT) PRIMARY KEY
PHONE_NUMBER (VARCHAR)
CONTACT_ID (INT) - Foreign key to the Contact table
```

Your sample data will look like

```
PHONE_NUMBER_ID     PHONE_NUMBER    CONTACT_ID
---------------     ------------     ----------
1                   734578956         1
2                   987546563         2
3                   987645643         2
```

This means Contact 1 has one phone number and contact 2 has 2 phone numbers.

Now you need a `Collection` property in your Contact class to store the PhoneNumbers

```
public class Contact
{
  public int ID { set;get;} 
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
  //Other contact related proerpties

  IList<string> PhoneNumbers { set;get;}

 public Contact()
 {
   if(PhoneNumbers==null)
       PhoneNumbers=new List<string>();
 }
}
```

Comment: I do not have contact class in models , i just have edmx file in model (i know i am pathetic , just began learning.

Comment: how do i mention that phone number should be stored in Contact table while rest of the data should be stored in Table1

Comment: @user1557976 you should update your Data Access Code to do that. Without knowing how it is, it is difficult to tell you more specifically what to do.